# Scrapy callback return vs yield

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

```
def parse_pagelist(self,response):
        for page in pageinfo:
            page_url=page['url']
            yield response.follow(page_url,self.parse_page)
        next_page=response.xpath('//ol[@class="page-main"]/li[last()]/a/@href').get()
        if next_page:
            return [response.follow(next_page,callback=self.parse_pagelist)]
```

In scrapy docs about spider.parse it says:

> This method, as well as any other Request callback, must return an iterable of >Request and/or item objects.

Here i return a **list** object contains scrapy.Request,but it never get download,why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Because **return** sends back a spesific value to its caller and your function will stop after one **return**, whereas **yield** produce a sequence of values and it will only stop the function when there are no more value to be yielded.

You may want to read about generator [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).

edit:
Here is and example that may ilustrate the problem:

```
def generate():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i
    return 15
result = [i for i in generate()]
```

The value of `result` variable will be `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`.

Generators uses `__next__` method to get the the value from next iteration, and value that is **return**ed is not inlcluded in that iteration. I hope this example will help you.

Comment: I know the difference between return and yield.Question is why the **callback** function in the `response.follow` at the **end** of parse_pagelist doesn't execute if i **return** it,and will be execute if i **yield** it

Comment: If you tried to make a function that yield some numbers and return a spesific number at the end, then the last number that **return**ed won't be iterated. I've add an example in my answer.

Comment: I edited my question,thanks for your kindness to help and ,but please try to understand the problem before you answer it.

Answer (score 0):

The `yield` in your callback makes your callback work as an iterator.

You must either use `yield`, or return a list. You cannot combine both.

Comment: But the return statement is at the end of my callback ,all the yields has been executed,why return a list won't work here?